# fribidi autogen.sh script failing: "autoreconf: error: automake failed with exit status: 1"

Tags: autogen

I am trying to install [fribidi](https://github.com/fribidi/fribidi), but I am getting the following error when running the *autogen.sh* script:

```
-n checking for pkg-config...
/usr/local/bin/pkg-config
-n checking for libtoolize...
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize
-n checking for autoreconf...
/usr/local/bin/autoreconf
running autoreconf --force --install --verbose
autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: glibtoolize --copy --force
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
glibtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.71/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:98: warning: The preprocessor macro `STDC_HEADERS' is obsolete.
configure.ac:98:   Except in unusual embedded environments, you can safely include all
configure.ac:98:   ISO C90 headers unconditionally.
configure.ac:129: warning: your code may safely assume C89 semantics that RETSIGTYPE is void.
configure.ac:129: Remove this warning and the `AC_CACHE_CHECK' when you adjust the code.
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.71/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.ac:40: installing './compile'
configure.ac:37: installing './missing'
configure.ac:31: error: version 'fribidi_version()' doesn't follow Gnits standards
bin/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
lib/Headers.mk:25: warning: shell cat $(top_srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
lib/Headers.mk:25: (probably a GNU make extension)
doc/Makefile.am:16:   'lib/Headers.mk' included from here
doc/Makefile.am:21: warning: shell sed '$$d' $(top_srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
doc/Makefile.am:21: (probably a GNU make extension)
gen.tab/Makefile.am:28: warning: 'CFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it;
gen.tab/Makefile.am:28: use 'AM_CFLAGS' instead
gen.tab/Makefile.am:29: warning: 'LDFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it;
gen.tab/Makefile.am:29: use 'AM_LDFLAGS' instead
lib/Headers.mk:25: warning: shell cat $(top_srcdir: non-POSIX variable name
lib/Headers.mk:25: (probably a GNU make extension)
lib/Makefile.am:15:   'lib/Headers.mk' included from here
autoreconf: error: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

I already installed *libtool* and *autoconf*. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What platform (incl. version)? [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa)? Or something else?

Comment: MacOS version 12.5